# Multiprocessing python-server creates too many temp-directories

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a server in python3.3 that has a separate thread preloaded to do all the processing for the incoming connections.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Queue
from multiprocessing.reduction import reduce_socket
import time
import socketserver,socket


def process(q):
    while 1:
        fn,args = q.get()
        conn = fn(*args)

        while conn.recv(1, socket.MSG_PEEK):
            buf = conn.recv(100)
            if not buf: break
            conn.send(b"Got it: ")
            conn.send(buf)

        conn.close()

class MyHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print("Opening connection")
        print("Processing")
        self.server.q.put(reduce_socket(self.request))
        while self.request.recv(1, socket.MSG_PEEK):
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Closing connection")

class MyServer(socketserver.ForkingTCPServer):
    p = Process
    q = Queue()
    parent_conn,child_conn = Pipe()
    def __init__(self,server_address,handler):
        socketserver.ForkingTCPServer.__init__(self,server_address, handler)
        self.p = Process(target=process,args=(self.q,))
        self.p.start()
    def __del__(self):
        self.p.join()


server_address = ('',9999)
myserver = MyServer(server_address,MyHandler)
myserver.serve_forever()
```

I can test that it works using the following script:

```
from multiprocessing.reduction import reduce_socket
import time
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 9999))

time.sleep(1)
print("reduce_socket(s)")
fn,args = reduce_socket(s)
time.sleep(1)
print("rebuild_socket(s)")
conn = fn(*args)
time.sleep(1)
print("using_socket(s)")

conn.send("poks")
print conn.recv(255)
conn.send("poks")
print conn.recv(255)
conn.send("")
print conn.recv(255)
conn.close()
```

Unfortunately there seems to be something that is wrong since after running the test for n times, my tmp-folder is filled with subfolders:

```
$ ls /tmp/pymp*|wc -l
32000
```

These temporary files are created by `socket_reduce()`. Interestingly the `rebuild/reduce_socket()` in the client also creates the temporary files, but they are removed once the function exits. The maximum amount of folders in my current tmp-filesystem is 32000 which causes a problem. I could remove the /tmp/pymp*-files by hand or somewhere in the server, but I guess there should also be the correct way to do this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't see in your code where a temporary file would be created.  Where are these subfolders coming from?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is the socket_reduce() that creates them.

Comment: From the code you've posted it seems you never do a `rebuild_socket`, which causes the temporary files to hang around since nothing claimed them yet.

Comment: If i'm correct, it should be the line with `conn = fn(*args)`, since `reduce_socket()` returns the function to use and the parameters as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Kind of fixed it. From the .`./lib/python3.3/multiprocessing/util.py:`

```
$ grep "def get_temp_dir" -B5 /usr/local/lib/python3.3/multiprocessing/util.py

#
# Function returning a temp directory which will be removed on exit
#

def get_temp_dir():
```

It seems that the temporary directory should be available until the process quits. Since my `process()` and `main()` both run forever, the temporary file won't be removed. To fix it I can create another process that will hand the reduced_socket to the `process()`:

```
def process(q):
    while 1:
        fn,args = q.get()
        conn = fn(*args)

        while conn.recv(1, socket.MSG_PEEK):
            buf = conn.recv(100)
            if not buf: break
            conn.send(b"Got it: ")
            conn.send(buf)

        conn.close()
        q.put("ok")



class MyHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def socket_to_process(self,q):
        q.put(reduce_socket(self.request))
        q.get()
    def handle(self):
        p = Process(target=self.socket_to_process,args=(self.server.q,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

This way the temporary file is created in a subprocess that will exit once the `process()` has done its thing with the input. I don't think this is an elegant way of doing it but it works. If someone knows better, please let stackoverflow know.